# Issue running OPENQUERY against linked server and using data from local tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

We have our SQL Server lets call it SQL_LOCAL and we have a linked Oracle server lets call OLINK.

I have a table in in SQL_LOCAL that holds 3 columns.

```
|  C_ID  |  CON_NUM  |  CUS_NUM  |
```

I need to use `CUS_NUM` to get data from the linked server OLINK.

Normally one would do something like this:

```
SELECT ST.C_ID
      ,ST.CON_NUM
      ,OT.CUS_NBR
      ,OT.A_ID
      ,OT.L_NBR
FROM SQL_LOCAL.TABLE_NAME ST
JOIN OLINK.TABLE_NAME AS OT
    ON ST.CUS_NBR = OT.CUS_NBR
```

However due to some odd datatype issue between Oracle and SQL Server I get this error:

> The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OLINK"
>   supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "V_IND"
>   (compile-time ordinal 4) of object ""DATABASE_NAME"."TABLE_NAME"" was
>   reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISFIXEDLENGTH" of 16 at compile time
>   and 0 at run time.

Currently how we get around this issue is to pass out queries using `OPENQUERY` and this works fine if we are only working with data on the linked server. However now I need to use tables from the SQL_LOCAL server against data on the OLINK linked server.

My current working method takes way to long as I cannot pass from the local tables to the OPENQUERY.
Here is my current working query:

```
SELECT ST.BCA_ID
    ,ST.CONTRACT_NBR
    ,OT.C_NBR
    ,OT.A_ID
    ,OT.LOOKUP_NBR
FROM OPENQUERY(CRS,
    'SELECT
         C_NBR
        ,A_ID
        ,LOOKUP_NBR
    FROM OLINK.TABLE_NAME') AS OT
JOIN SQL_LOCAL.TABLE_NAME ST
ON OT.C_NBR = OT.C_NBR
```

As you can see this is not very efficient as it consist of a full table scan for the OPENQUERY but I do get the expected results. However this just wont be good enough for our project. This will eat up way to much spool space.

I have no choice but to use OPENQUERY here and I have no other choice to start my connection against out SQL_LOCAL server. These 2 things I cannot change so any ideas that do not involve these 2 requirements wont work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you change your error so that it relates to the SQL query please? `""DATABASE_NAME"."TABLE_NAME""` isn't in your SQL statement, so is pretty meaningless to us. What column does that *actually* refer to in your SQL statement, and what data types are involved (Oracle and SQL Server sides).

Comment: @Larnu It does not matter what `""DATABASE_NAME"."TABLE_NAME""` refers to as even if that column is not part of the select statement it still causes the error. In fact the column that is the problem is not part of my select statement. I already know what the problem is and that  is why we have no choice but to use OPENQUERY against the Oracle linked server.

Comment: So, does `SELECT OT.CUS_NBR
      ,OT.A_ID
      ,OT.L_NBR FROM OLINK.TABLE_NAME;` produce the error?

Comment: @Larnu if I do not use OPENQUERY then yes